# Can we use Cloud Pub/Sub as Celery Broker in Airflow CeleryExecutor?

Tags: airflow, celery, google-cloud-pubsub

I wanted to deploy airflow on GCP and I wanted to use CeleryExecutor. Instead of using Redis or RabbitMQ as the broker, I want to have a serverless broker for Celery.

I notice that SQS can be used as a broker so I think Cloud Pub/Sub as GCP version of AWS SQS can also be used as a broker.